# Java Javamail variables inside html

Tags: java, html, variables, jakarta-mail

I'm using [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) for Java to send out emails to multiple people and so I need to use variables to make each email personal. Now my question is how do I use normal java variables like strings and ints inside the HTML code of an email.

Here is my code

```
try {                     
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));

  MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
  BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  message.setSubject(title + " has reached your desired price!");
  String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1> <H2> hi </H2> <img src=\"cid:image\">" + price_desired;

  messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(folderPath + image_title);
  messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
  messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
  multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
  message.setContent(multipart);
  Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
  transport.connect(host, from, pass);
  transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
  transport.close();
  System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
  mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see I can add variables at the end of the email however how do I do it inside the HTML and how do I make the font size etc same for the variables as the normal code. I'm sorry if this was asked before but I was unable to find anything and I searched here on Stack Overflow and Google.

---

**EDIT** - For anyone wondering the answer is

```
String htmlText = "<H1>Hello. The price desired is " + price_desired + "</H1>
```

when I initially tried something similar it didn't work but when I copied this code I could then easily change it around.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Dude. Change you profile picture. I tried reading this so many times. It is so distracting. Ha.

Comment: have you looked @velocity?

Comment: :DDD sorry Dut I can't when I try to change it I get distracted :D

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the variable inside the htmlText string instead of at the end.

```
String htmlText = "<H1>Hello. The price desired is " + price_desired + "</H1> <H2> hi </H2> <img src=\"cid:image\">";
```

If you are going to be concatenating several variables you may want to use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation.

```
StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
htmlBuilder.append("<H1>").append("Hello ").append(price_desired).append("</H1>");
htmlBuilder.append("<H2>").append(var2).append("</H2>");
messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlBuilder.toString(), "text/html");
```

You may also want to look into `String.format(...)`

Answer (score 0):

What about Java's standard [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) "[formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)"?

```
String.format ( Locale.US, "<h1>Hi my friend %0$s</h1> <p>This is your pic: <img src=\"%1$s\"></p>", friendName, pictureURL );
```

Formatter syntax: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Comment: This is a great solution as is `java.text.MessageFormat` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>
Variable Name: "+ Variable Value+" 
</h2> .
```